# Is there a better way to split an array into a string

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass an Array to a method and then return a string I can use for a SQL WHERE clause.  I have the following and it works just fine.  But is there a better way?  I am looking for one of the two results;

1. `WHERE (ColumnName IN (12, 34, 56, 78, 90))`
2. `WHERE (ColumnName IN ('12', '34', '56', '78', '90'))`

---

```
    public static string setInSearchFilter(string psSearchFilter, string psColumnName, 
        string[] paObjectValues, bool pbIsString)
    {
        string lsDelimiter = "'", lsRetVal = string.Empty, lsObjectValues = string.Empty;

        if (!pbIsString)
        {
            lsDelimiter = string.Empty;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(psSearchFilter))
        {
            lsRetVal = psSearchFilter + " AND ";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= paObjectValues.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            lsObjectValues += lsDelimiter + paObjectValues[i] + lsDelimiter;

            if (i < paObjectValues.GetUpperBound(0))
            {
                lsObjectValues += ", ";
            }
        }

        return lsRetVal += "(" + psColumnName + " IN (" + lsObjectValues + "))";
    }
```

Comment: See string.Join and the many duplicates. FWIW: I *recommend* using (dynamically added) placeholders, as SQL is SQL.

Comment: Have you looked into paramaterized queries or other forms of sanitized input?  This code is just begging for a sql injection attack.

Comment: @YYY - Yes, I will be doing a paramaterized query.  Just trying to get this to work first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, `string.Join`:

```
string.Format(
    "({0}" + string.Join("{0},{0}", paObjectValues) + "{0})",
    lsDelimiter 
);
```

This assumes there's something in the list, so make sure to throw or return if the filter set is empty.

You might also consider doing some kind of validation on the items to prevent SQL injection:

```
if (paObjectValues.Any(item => !int.TryParse(item))) 
    throw new Exception("Items must be numeric");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add parameters for every option (allowing query-plan re-use and injection-safety), or I would investigate a "split" UDF. Or, better, I'd use something like an ORM or micro-ORM which may often have this type of capability built in. For example, with LINQ you can often use an array/list and Contains. Or with "dapper" you can use a subtle variant of the IN syntax which expands the inputs into separate parameters - specifically: `where x.Foo in @bar` becomes `where x,Foo in (@bar0, @bar1, @bar2)` if the "bar" parameter has 3 values.